# Trying to load data from google storage bucket results in a apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403... returned "Forbidden">

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

so right now im trying to write a python script which loads a few files from our google storage. I'm using Windows, have installed the Google Cloud SDK and set everything up with gsutil so i can succesfully load a file in typing the following the the commandline:

`gsutil cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_****/financial-stats/subscriptions/***.csv .`

This loads a correct csv file to my folder. Cool.

Now i tried the same in python, following this documentation from google: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en (you have to click on "Download reports using a client library & service account" and then on "Python example" to show the python code)

I used the exact same code

```
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from apiclient.discovery import build
from urllib import quote

client_email = 'serviceAccountEmail'
json_file = 'pathToMyServiceAccountPrivateKey'
cloud_storage_bucket = 'pubsite_prod_rev_******'
report_to_download = 'financial-stats/subscriptions/fileName.csv'

print report_to_download

private_key = json.loads(open(json_file).read())['private_key']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, private_key, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only')

storage = build('storage', 'v1', http=credentials.authorize(Http()))

print storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket, object=report_to_download).execute()
```

to load the csv file.Unfortunetaley this result in the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Office/Financial Reports/Python Reporter/Test.py", line 66, in <module>
    print storage.objects().get(bucket=cloud_storage_bucket, object=report_to_download).execute()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bq\third_party\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bq\third_party\apiclient\http.py", line 724, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
apiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/pubsite_prod_rev_17179175168453545219/o/financial-stats%2Fsubscriptions%2Fsubscriptions_de.kaasahealth.namagi_cody_monthly_sub_201701_device.csv?alt=json returned "Forbidden">
```

So obviously there is something wrong with the URL it builds. But i dont know what exactly, as it is the same thing google tells us to do on the doc page.

Hope someone can help me out here :/

EDIT: I changed the traceback, as it changed from error 404 to error 403 now..

Answer (score 0):

Alright so the reason why it did not work was pretty... easy.
You have to enable access and add Admin rights or less (but i didn try out the other possibilities) inside the google dev console though Settings -> API Acess and selct the service account you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It means you do now have permissions to download reports from

Google Play Console -> Download Reports -> Financial (or something related to financial reports).

There you can download the same files you're trying to download via `gsutil`.
Once you have permissions to download reports from Google Play Console you will be able to download it with `gsutil` or programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You will need admin access or at least account-level permission for "**View app information and download bulk reports (read-only)**"

Once the permissions are updated, it'd take about 24 hours for the downloads to work.

[image]